# Was Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann inspired by Alastair Reynolds' Revelation Space?

Tags: gurren-lagann

This might not have an answer, but after watching TTGL (2007), I've realized that it is *extremely* similar to Alastair Reynolds' Revelation Space universe (2000) and the plotline of his original trilogy:

- In TTGL, Beastmen/Gunmen prevent humans from technologically evolving by keeping them underground, and then later the anti-Spirals
- In Revelation Space, the Inhibitors prevent sentient species from expanding beyond their local bubble
- In TTGL, the moon is actually a spaceship that was used as a weapon by the anti-spirals
- In Revelation Space, one of the moons (or was it a dwarf planet) of Resurgam was in fact a beacon station that would alert the Inhibitors to eradicate life on a planet (like the moon would be used in TTGL)
- In TTGL, the reason that the anti-spirals tried to eradicate all spiral species is because of the Spiral Nemesis, a force that would end all life in the Universe
- In Revelation Space, the Inhibitors eradicate life because

> eventually the [Andromedia-Milky Way collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda%E2%80%93Milky_Way_collision) will destroy the galaxy and render it incapable of supporting life without not just terraforming, but system-forming by a single species

Is this just a coincidence, or is there any evidence that the creators of TTGL were fans of Alastair Reynolds' work?